# using jQuery/ajax for GET request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to send an input to be processed on another page but I'm having some trouble getting it to work.

When I open up the network console I can see a GET method set to common_functions, but there's no variables attached to it. I'm getting this

```
http://localhost/project/common_functions.php
```

instead of something like

```
http://localhost/project/common_functions.php?name=abcdef
```

Here's my HTML. It's fine as far as I know because I get an alert from the function receiving the input

```
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Project Name</td><td><input type = "textbox" name="project_name" id = "project_name" onkeyup = "get_name(this.value);" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Project Description</td><td><input type = "textbox" name="project_name" id = "project_description" onkeyup = "get_description(this.value);"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit_project"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here's the jQuery. I'm attempting to send a GET request.

```
function get_name(name){
    var project_name = name;
    $.get('common_functions.php', function(name) {
        alert(project_name); //this displays the name
        $('#project_name').html(name);
    });
}
```

When I have just this I get an alert, so I know it's at least acknowledging the onkeyup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending any data. You can either append the data to the script name or send it as key - value pairs:

```
$.get('common_functions.php', {'project_name': name}, function(data) {
```

And I would not use the same variable name in the callback function, that only leads to confusion.

Comment: Tried this, but now the GET request doesn't show in the network console.

Comment: @user1852176 That sounds like a syntax error somewhere, can you post the complete javascript code?

Comment: @user1852176 The same code you have, I have only added `, {'project_name': name}` in that line.

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting to see is if you called your get function with the following parameter.

```
var url = 'common_functions.php?project_name=' + Name;

$.get(url , function(name) {
    alert(project_name); //this displays the name
    $('#project_name').html(name);
});
```

The second parameter is just the return function, this is what will get called when your call to common_functions.php returns.

The nicest way to do it is as @jeroen has shown.